# Excel - VBA somar +1 a linha

Tags: vba

Tenho uma questão .

Tenho andado a testar as macros para preencher uma base de dados mas estou com um problema.

ID - Nome

ZZ1 - A

ZZ2 - B

Como consigo somar isto automaticamente? (Agora ZZ3)
Tenho o seguinte código que funciona com apenas numeros. Já tentei varias formas mas dá sempre erro por causa das variaveis.

```
Sub novo()
 Dim codigo, x As Double

'Descobre a ultima linha
 x = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 If x = 1 Then
    codigo = x
 Else
    codigo = Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1) + 1
End If
'Adiciona o novo Código
Sheets(1).Range("F5") = codigo
'Limpar campos
End Sub
```

Comment: Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/325571/75104)

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT:

### Regex

#### Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

#### Padrão

Um Regex simples que identifica se possui números `\d+` e se possui letras sem caracteres especiais `[a-zA-Z]+`

### Código em Excel VBA

```
Dim codigo As String, x As Long
Dim objMatches As Object, objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
'Regex
objRegExp.Pattern = "\d+"
objRegExp.Global = True

'Descobre a ultima linha
x = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If x = 1 Then
    codigo_novo = x
Else
    codigo = Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)
    Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(codigo)
    If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each m In objMatches
            numero = CLng(m) + 1
        Next m
    End If
    objRegExp.Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]+"
     Set objMatches = objRegExp.Execute(codigo)
    If objMatches.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each m In objMatches
            letras = m
        Next m
    End If
End If

codigo_novo = letras & numero
'Adiciona o novo Código
Sheets(1).Range("F5") = codigo_novo
```

### Resposta Original

#### 1 - Declarações

Deste modo `Dim codigo, x As Double` você está declarando somente x como Double e codigo está como Variant, que o Excel tenta encontrar o tipo de dados (data type) da variável. O correto seria: `Dim codigo As Double, x As Long`

Utilize a variável Long para obter a última linha, pois linhas são números inteiros, porém se você declarar como Integer, ocorrerá erros se passar de 32767 Linhas. Já o Long pode ir até 2147483647

#### 2 - Última Linha

Você não está especificando a planilha corretamente para encontrar a última linha, você pode realizar isto de várias maneiras. Segue o exemplo de duas:

`x = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Ou

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheets
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
With ws2
    x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Outros códigos com a Planilha2 podem ser usados com .Cells, sem especificar a planilha em questão
End With
```

#### 3 - Soma

Você está realizando uma operação de somar o valor da célula com 1, portanto, se quiser somar o número da linha: `codigo = Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1).Row + 1`

Mas se quiser somar o valor da célula e ela está como texto, tente converter para Double primeiro: `codigo = CDbl(Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)) + 1`

Para somar Letras, junte duas Strings: `codigo = CStr(Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)) & "1"`

Ou se também há Letras nesta coluna, pode-se verificar se a célula é um número:

```
 Dim codigo As Double, x As Long

'Descobre a ultima linha
 x = Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

 If x = 1 Then
    codigo = x
 Else
    If IsNumeric(CDbl(Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1).Value)) Then
        codigo = CDbl(Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1).Value) + 1
    Else
        codigo = xlErrNA
    End If
End If
'Adiciona o novo Código
Sheets(1).Range("F5") = codigo
'Limpar campos
```

Comment: Eu estou a tentar somar a coluna ID que contem a Letra sempre igual "ZZ"+ 1 . Quero conseguir somar e manter sempre o ZZ. 

Se no campo ID apenas estiver numeros ele funciona como coloquei.

Comment: Para somar Letras, junte duas Strings: `codigo = CStr(Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)) & "1"`

Comment: Correto, As letras mantem sempre igual mas o numero aumenta +1 . Assim dá erro : codigo = CStr(Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)) + 1

Comment: Como você realmente deseja, dê exemplos mais claros. Do modo que você está fazendo, tentando somar String com um Número, ocorrerão erros.

Comment: Genero ZZ1 .. Agora quero que ele gere o ZZ2

Comment: Somar sempre o numero +1

Answer (score -1):

Para extrair os números, pode usar a função VALUE do Excel, que converte uma string numérica para um valor numérico.

Para adicionar os números de volta ao código ID, pode usar a função TEXT, que converte um valor numérico para uma string.

```vb
Sub novo()
Dim codigo, x As Double

'Descobre a ultima linha
x = Sheets(2).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If x = 1 Then
   codigo = "ZZ1"
Else
   codigo = text(value(Sheets(2).Cells(x, 1)) + 1, "ZZ")
End If

'Adiciona o novo Código
Sheets(1).Range("F5") = codigo
'Limpar campos
End Sub
```