# Incrementar em String em VBA excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Uma Strign em VBA excel tem o seguinte valor: "T110A17014". Preciso incrementar esta string a cada iteração. Para incrementar apenas a ultima posição o código abaixo funciona! 
Agora se tivermos este valor: "T110A17099" e usarmos o código abaixo ficará assim: "T110A170910"! Como incrementar corretamente para que "T110A17099" fique: "T110A17100"?

```
Dim TB As String = "T110A17014", txtBOX As String, Array() As String, x As Integer, I As Integer

If Not IsEmpty(TB) And TB <> "" Then      
     Array = TextBoxTOArray(TB) 
     x = Array(UBound(Array)) + 1
     For I = LBound(Array) To UBound(Array) - 1    
             txtBOX = txtBOX & Array(I) 
     Next
     TB = txtBOX & x 
End If
```

Comment: Não consegues separar a parte numérica da string? Depois só tinhas de incrementar como sendo um numero e voltar a concatenar.

Comment: Isso! Neste caso temos 5 posições numéricas depois de uma letra; em outros casos teremos 3 posições numéricas depois de uma letra.

Comment: Pois deduzido algo desse género :/ E se percorreres a string, inversamente até encontrares o caracter que não é um numero, e depois, só incrementas nessa parte da string, não sei se é uma sugestão viável.

Comment: É exatamente isso que pretendo fazer! Usando o código acima poderia percorrer de traz para frente e resolveria (teoricamente). Mas antevejo um código enorme aninhado. Precisamos de algo mais esperto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução é a utilização de Expressões Regulares.

### Expressão Regular

A seguinte expressão pode ser utilizada: `\d+(?=$)`

Em que esta expressão captura um ou mais dígitos `\d+` antes do fim da string `(?=$)`

E a [demo pode ser vista neste link](https://regex101.com/r/upzjnq/3)

#### Habilitar o Regex no Excel

1. RegEx precisa ser habilitado, [Habilite o modo Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)
2. Na aba 'Desenvolvedor', clique em 'Visual Basic' e a janela do VBA irá abrir.
3. Vá em 'Ferramentas' -> 'Referências...' e uma janela abrirá.
4. Procure por 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5', como na imagem abaixo. E habilite esta opção.

[image: Janela Referências]

### Código

```
Dim numero As Long
Dim codigo As String, resultado As String
Dim objCorresp As Object, objExpReg As Object
Set objExpReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
'Expressão Regular
objExpReg.Pattern = "\d+(?=$)"
objExpReg.Global = True

codigo = "T110A17099"
Set objCorresp = objExpReg.Execute(codigo)
    If objCorresp.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each c In objCorresp
            numero = CLng(c) + 1
            codigo = Replace(codigo, c, "")
        Next c
    End If
resultado = codigo & numero
MsgBox (resultado)
```

### Código de Função (UDF)

```
Function funcao_incrementar(codigo As String) As String

Dim numero As Long
Dim objCorresp As Object, objExpReg As Object
Set objExpReg = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
'Expressão Regular
objExpReg.Pattern = "\d+(?=$)"
objExpReg.Global = True

Set objCorresp = objExpReg.Execute(codigo)
    If objCorresp.Count <> 0 Then
        For Each c In objCorresp
            numero = CLng(c) + 1
            codigo = Replace(codigo, c, "")
        Next c
    End If
funcao_incrementar = codigo & numero
End Function
```

#### Testando

```
Sub teste()
    MsgBox (funcao_incrementar("T110A17099"))
End Sub
```

Comment: danieltakeshi san, o que eh Função UDF?

Comment: User Defined Function, é uma função criada pelo VBA. Daí você pode usá-laa ou na planilha ou em uma Sub.